# When: $ \int_A f d \mu \leq \mu(A) \int_A f d \lambda$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Under which minimal conditions on the function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and the measure $\mu$ also on $\mathbb{R}^+$ we have:

$$ \int_A f d \mu \leq \mu(A) \int_A f d \lambda$$

for $\lambda$ Lebesgue measure and $A$ non empty measurable set? Is it enough to ask $f$ to be nonnegative and $\mu$ a nonnegative finite measure?

Comment: I think you will also need $\mu$ to be absolutely continuous with $\lambda$.